# Integration in R language

Tags: r, math, numeric

I'm trying to compute the integral between 1 and some cutoff 'cut' of the function given in the R-code below as 'int'. It depends on 2 parameters dM[i] and dLambda[j] defined before I make the integration and for each pair I save the results in vector 'vec':

```
vec = c() #vector for INT values: this is our goal
dM = seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 0.01) #vector for mass density parameter
dLambda = seq(from = -1.5, to = 3, by = 0.01) #vector for vacuum energy density parameter

for (i in 1:length(dM)) {
  for (j in 1:length(dLambda)) {

    int = function(x) ((dM[i]*x^4*(x - 1) + dLambda[j]*x^2*(1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2))
    cut = 30
    INT_data = integrate(int, 1, cut)
    INT = INT_data$value
    vec = c(vec, INT)
  }
}
```

But when I run the script I get the error: "Error in integrate(int, 1, cut) : non-finite function value
". Nonetheless, if I tried the following code

```
int = function(x) ((0*x^4*(x - 1) -1.5*x^2*(1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2))
cut = 30
INT_data = integrate(int, 1, cut)
INT = INT_data$value
vec = c(vec, INT)
```

I get the correct result without any error. So the error above is not true, it can calculate the integral but it seems that R cannot work it out if I use the 2 'for'-loops. How can I re-write the code so I can compute all the different values for dM[i] and dLambda[j] I want?

Comment: You should print out i and j in your loop to find which ones lead to the error.  Probably only some particular values fail, i.e. the values where the denominator in your function is zero.

Comment: @user2554330 once I reach dM[i] = 0 and dLambda[j] = 1 I get the failure. I guess it is because of the x = 0 point, but I have removed that prosibility changing x -> x + reg with reg = 0.001 and I still get an error that says NaNs are produced. But I don't understand it because with reg I have erased the possibility of NaN

Comment: @user2554330 Ok, it seems that the integral for those values onwards is divergent indeed. But how could I avoid this error so I can keep calculating? I mean, that the programme doesn't stop

Comment: You can use the `try()` function to keep going after errors, i.e. `INT_data <- try(integrate(int, 1, cut)); if (inherits(INT_data, "try-error")) INT_data <- NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is only defined for some values of `dM` and `dLambda`.  You can use the `try()` function to attempt evaluation, but not stop in case an error occurs.

It's also a lot more efficient to pre-allocate the object to hold the results; running `vec = c(vec, INT)` gradually grows it, and that's very slow, because R needs to keep creating new vectors just one element longer than the last one.

This code fixes both issues, and then plots the result:

```r
dM <- seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 0.01) #vector for mass density parameter
dLambda <- seq(from = -1.5, to = 3, by = 0.01) #vector for vacuum energy density parameter
result <- matrix(NA, length(dM), length(dLambda))

for (i in 1:length(dM)) {
  for (j in 1:length(dLambda)) {

    int <- function(x) ((dM[i]*x^4*(x - 1) + dLambda[j]*x^2*(1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2))
    cut <- 30
    INT_data <- try(integrate(int, 1, cut), silent = TRUE)
    if (!inherits(INT_data, "try-error")) 
      result[i, j] <- INT_data$value
  }
}
image(dM, dLambda, result)
```

**Edited to add:**  Here's how this works. If `integrate` signals an error in your original code, the loop will stop.  `try()` prevents that.  If there's no error, it returns the result of the `integrate` call.  If there is an error, it returns an object with information about the error.  That object has class `"try-error"`, so the check `if (!inherits(INT_data, "try-error"))` is basically asking "Was there an error?"  If there was an error, nothing happens, and that entry of the `result` is left as `NA`, as it was initialized.  The loop then goes on to try the next `dM`, `dLambda` pair.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, but I have 3 doubts still: 1) what is try() really doing? If for some 'x', integrate() ends up in a NaN, is it just ignoring that NaN but continuing with the same integral (amin, the same dM[i], dLambda[j])? 2) I've been looking for info. about 'inherits' and I just found that it is somehow related to classes. How does it work? 3) 'try-error' is for... ?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: I've been looking for some kind of temperature map legend for the graphic you get in your answer, but I don't see how to produce it. My aiming is to get a legend for that graphic which tell us the integral's value

Comment: `contour()` or `filled.contour()` may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mathematical rather than being related to coding. The function is not defined for the whole domain you are integrating. With dM[1] = 0 and dLambda > 1, your expression

```
(dM[i]*x^4*(x - 1) + dLambda[j]*x^2*(1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2)
```

simplifies to

```
(dLambda[j] * x^2 * (1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2)
```

so let's take dLambda[j] at 1.01, which is where your calculation stops:

```
(1.01 * x^2 * (1 - x^2) + x^4)^(-1/2)
```

which is

```
(1.01 * x^2 - 1.01 * x^4 + x^4)^(-1/2)
```

or

```
(1.01 * x^2 - 0.01 x^4)^(-1/2)
```

Now, you are evaluating x between 1 and 30. So what happens when x = 11?

```
(1.01 * 121 - 0.01 * 14641)^(-1/2)
```

This leaves you

```
(122.21 - 146.41)^(-1/2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
1/sqrt(-24.2)
```

So the reason for the error is that you are integrating a function in a domain in which it is undefined.

The function is badly behaved for other values of dM too, with infinite peaks in the midst of the range, so even using the `integrate(..., stop.on.error = F)` option won't allow you to keep calculating because you will get an infinite sum.